# Сравнить строки двух файлов txt Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребят у меня есть 1.txt и 2.txt, как мне взять проверить все строки на совпадение с 2.txt и если есть совпадение то записать в good.txt, в гугле похожее нашёл ну не понял как допилить.

```
end_list = open('1.txt','w')
listdir = open('2.txt')
order_set = set(open('order_fix.txt').readlines())

for line in listdir.readlines():
   if line in order_set:
       end_list.write(line)
```

Comment: Чем плохо ваше текущее решение? Оно не работает?

Answer (score 1):

В `Python` у множеств есть функция `intersection`, которая позволяет получить пересечение двух множеств.

Можно считать два файла, преобразовать список строк в два отдельных множества, после чего получить совпадающие строки при помощи этой функции.

И да, лучше при открытии файла использовать контекстный менеджер `with`, который автоматически закрывает файл по завершению работы, что позволит не тратить лишние ресурсы.

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as end_list, open('2.txt', 'r') as listdir:
    equal_strings = set(end_list).intersection(listdir)

with open('good.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in equal_strings:
        f.write(line)
```

Подсмотрел решение на англоязычном SO в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19007888/19736488).

Comment: Спасибо. А как по завершению показать что проверка закончилась? Просто не пойму как поймать завершение скрипта

Comment: можно открыть два файла в `with`: `with open(...) as a, open(...) as b:`

Comment: @Danis спасибо, поправил!

Comment: Вы склеили все одинаковые строки из `1.txt` и нарушили их порядок. Это предусмотрено?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy строки не склеиваются, в файл записываются корректно, проверьте, по поводу порядка - такого условия не было

Comment: Если в 1.txt десять раз посторена одна и та же строка, вы выведе её один раз. Это один из смыслов глагола "склеить". Обычно фильтрация (а задача - именно фильтрация) не предусматривает удаление дубликатов и нарушения порядка. В этой задаче это важно, так можно решить её быстрее, в меньшей памяти с сохранением дубликатов и порядка.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а мне кажется удаление дубликатов весьма логичным и соответствующим условию задачи, нужно вывести повторяющиеся строки в двух файлах, если строка идентична, то нет смысла выводить ее много раз, если же в задаче будет указано про фильтрацию, то я согласен, решение будет в корне другим, потому что тогда приведение к множеству не будет иметь смысла.

Comment: @МишаИванов любым принтом

Comment: У меня файл весит 2гиг и формат TSV если я возьму файл txt где 300мб и сравню с этим файлом 2гиг формат TSV то не получится же?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы допилил так: из `2.txt` делаем можество хороших строк. Открываем `1.txt` на чтение и `good.txt` на запись. Переписываем строку из `1.txt` в `good.txt` если она "хороша" - если она есть в множестве `good`:

```
with open('2.txt') as f2:
    good = set(f2)

with open('1.txt') as f1, open('good.txt', 'w') as fg:
    for line in f1:
        if line in good:
            fg.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('2.txt', 'r') as file2, open('good.txt', 'w') as good_file:
    set1 = set(line.strip() for line in file1)
    set2 = set(line.strip() for line in file2)
    intersection = set1.intersection(set2)
    for line in intersection:
        good_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Этот код открывает три файла: 1.txt, 2.txt и good.txt. Затем он создает множества set1 и set2 из строк в файлах 1.txt и 2.txt соответственно, удаляя переносы строк с помощью метода strip(). Затем находит пересечение множеств с помощью метода intersection() и записывает найденные строки в файл good.txt с помощью цикла for и метода write().